# error running capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

This is my first time using capistrano and i am getting the following error

```
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deployer/apps/cf/releases/20121115211351; true"
    servers: ["208.68.37.172"]
    [208.68.37.172] executing command
    command finished in 9420ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/cf/releases/20121115211351 && bundle install --gemfile /home/deployer/apps/cf/releases/20121115211351/Gemfile --path /home/deployer/apps/cf/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on 208.68.37.172
```

I dont even understand the error message. any help to fix this. Thanks

Comment: There would be an error message before the "rolling back" line. What is it?

Comment: there is no error message just a completed notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's saying that if failed to run that command on the host 208.68.37.172.  This command:

```
sh -c 'cd /home/deployer/apps/cf/releases/20121115211351 && bundle install --gemfile /home/deployer/apps/cf/releases/20121115211351/Gemfile --path /home/deployer/apps/cf/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'"
```

If it's not giving you any other info, you can tweak your configuration to remove `--quiet` from the bundle command to get more output, or run it manually on the server to see what's going on.

Comment: its a vps server and the repo is on github

Answer (score 0):

The thing to understand about capistrano is that is mostly runs commands remotely via ssh, so you can break out a given command by trying something like `ssh someuser@somehost somecommand`, where "somecommand" is the line that failed.  To get closer to the problem, first ssh into the host, and run the command (for example `sh -c 'cd /home/deployer'` is the command `cd /home/deployer`), and if that doesn't return an error `&&` will succeed, and attempt to run the next one `bundle install ...`

The most common cause of capistrano errors is the user not having adequate permissions, although in your case if you're failing on `bundle install` are you using RVM locally -- if so, is it set up on the deployer server?